# ReSharper warning still shown with UsedImplicitlyAttribute

Tags: c#, resharper, warnings

ReSharper warns me about a private method not being called. It is called through reflection, so I don't want to delete the method, and (partly) for this purpose `UsedImplicitlyAttribute` was designed. But ReSharper still warns me, even after decorating the method with that attribute. It seems like a bug, but perhaps I'm missing some option (ReSharper doesn't have too few of those). Does anyone have a clue how I can fix that? Building the project didn't work.

Comment: There are two ways to use R# code annotation attributes in your own code: referencing `JetBrains.Annotations.dll`, or incorporating the attribute declarations in your code. Which are you using?

Comment: I incorporate the declarations in my own code. But I couldn't have made a mistake in copy/pasting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've read [the documentation on how to incorporate the Code Annotations items into your own code](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html). I have found in the past that R# can be a *little* flaky with this part of the options:

[image: R# options page]

It sometimes takes more than one visit to this page before the namespace that you've copied the declarations into appears in the list. But once it does, and you tick the checkbox, it should all then work.